# AddRows receiving PHP Array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, google-visualization

I'm strugling getting data from PHP into a graph. I have the following pieces of code on 1 php page. First the simple part:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT timestamp, CurrentKelvin, TargetKelvin, WeatherTempKelvin FROM  `rawdata` ORDER BY  `rawdata`.`timestamp` DESC LIMIT 10) AS ttbl ORDER BY `timestamp` ASC;";
$results = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$ChartData = array();
    foreach($results as $result) 
    { 
        $ChartData[] = array( (int)$result['CurrentKelvin'],(int)$result['TargetKelvin']);
    }
    $ChartData = json_encode($ChartData);
```

Then the javascript part:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('number', 'CurrentKelvin');
      data.addColumn('number', 'TargetKelvin');
      alert( <?php echo json_encode($ChartData); ?>);

      data.addRows( <?php echo json_encode($ChartData); ?> );
      var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data);
    }
</script>

<!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

When i run the above the alert command shows the following output:

```
[[292,290],[292,290],[291,290],[291,290],[291,290],[291,290],[291,290],[291,290],[291,290],[291,290]]
```

But the data.addRows line generates the following error:
Error: Argument given to addRows must be either a number or an array

Changing the data.addRows to something simple (and changing data.addColumn to string, with the same array construction, I do get a graph:

```
data.addRows([
  ['Ivan', 5],
  ['Igor', 7],
  ['Felix', 8],
  ['Bob', 4] 
]);
```

I just can't figure out what is going wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: if you data.addRows method requires array as parameter .. you will have to either send the $charData as it is i.e without encoding.. or convert it in javascript array format.

Comment: try this - var json_arr = <?php echo json_encode($ChartData); ?>; data.addRows(JSON.parse(json_arr)))

Answer (score 1):

Answer given by Dinesh worked:

```
      var json_arr = <?php echo json_encode($ChartData); ?>; 
      data.addRows(JSON.parse(json_arr));
```